# Rails 4, AJAX, js.erb, missing template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to get the idea of AJAX rendering a template into the index page. Can anyone help me understand how Rails render "next.js.erb" rather than looking for "next.html.erb"?

routes.rb

```
get 'index' => 'products#index'
get 'next' => 'products#next'
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= @products.first.price %>
<%= link_to "Next", action:"next", remote: true %>
<div class="box"></div>
```

next.js.erb

```
(".box").html(<%= j render("nextitem") %>
```

_nextitem.html.erb

```
<%= @products.second.price %>
```

In products_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
end

def next
    @products = Product.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end
end
```

Comment: How are you sending the request `/next`?

Comment: When you specify 'remote: true' for a form or link Rails automagically generates the ajax request for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start off by adding a resources route to your `routes.rb` page instead of specifying every unique route:

```
resources :products, only: [:index] do
    member do
        post 'next'
    end
end
```

Then your `index.html.erb` page's link can look like:

```
<%= link_to "Next", next_product_path(@product), remote: true %>
```

Your `products_controller.rb` needs to specify a specific `@product` in the `def next` method, which you can pull from your `@products` collection (you can find the last product you displayed and retrieve the next one, or however you wish to do it).

`next.js.erb` can then do this (which renders the `_next_item.html.erb` partial, passing the `@product` instance variable defined in the controller as a local variable named `product`):

```
$(".box").html("<%= j render 'nextitem', product: @product %>");
```

And lastly in `_nextitem.html.erb` you can simply format the `product` local variable however you want it in the html before it's rendered and replaces what you currently have on your page, i.e.:

```
<div><%= product.price %></div>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or if anything wasn't quite clear enough!

-Dave

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Thanks Yumiko! If my answer helped you solve your problem, can you please accept it? If it didn't help you solve it yet, let me know how else I can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change next.js.erb to this:

```
$(".box").html("<%=j render 'nextitem ' %>")
```

Comment: Missing partial historical_prices/_next, application/_next with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/yumiko/Desktop/portfolio/EarningReport/app/views"

Comment: @yumiko my bad I thought partial was named next, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you simply request the page at `/next`, it will look for an `html.erb` template. To render a `js` template, you need to append `.js` at the end of request like `localhost:3000/next.js`. And the same is true for JSON response. For a JSON response, you need to append `.json` at the end of the URL.

Or if you are using jQuery to fetch the response from the server, you need to pass `dataType: script` to render JS format instead of HTML format.

Comment: when you specify remote true in a link, it automatically sends a js request to server

Comment: Missing template historical_prices/next, application/next with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/yumiko/Desktop/portfolio/EarningReport/app/views"

Comment: I know how to do it with fetch response from the server. However, I want to ajax a pretty long table, that's why im looking for the Ajax Rendering.